# How a line works as Swing button?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

I am creating lines and other components and want them to respond like a Swing button events as  a line would be clickable :

```
    class CustomLine extends JComponent {

        private int destx = 100;
        private int desty = 100;
        private int startx = 0;
        private int starty = 0;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawLine(startx, starty, destx, desty);
        }

    }
```

how this works?

Comment: Do you intend to have slanting lines or do you just need horizontal and vertical lines?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a math problem.  You need to find the equation of the line and then find the distance from point (mouse click).
The math is done for you, for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html)

You will also need to figure out handling mouse [events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29).

Answer (score 0):

What about extending it from JButton?
Just overrive the paint-Method like you did with JComponent and use it like a normal Button.
I'm not sure, if you need to alter the Border, too. I'm not familiar with altering GUI-Elements, but maybe this should do the trick.

Comment: this way the entire rectangle which has the line as a diagonal would be clickable.

Comment: just tried it for myself after posting this and recognized the same thing. would be too easy, i guess :/